# Copy row from one sheet and insert copied row under last row in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am in need of your expert assistance.

I am trying to write some code that will copy rows and insert the copied row below the last row in another sheet.

I have a Global sheet that has the data i will be copying. It will need to look in column Q.

I think the problem will be when trying to copy the data, the data in column G is the text name of a Contract Code. But the sheets are name with the Number version.

for example i have a row that has BRREPAIRS in column Q, I need this to copy to Sheet 2870, then i have a row that has BRVOIDS in column Q, I need this to copy to Sheet 2781.

I could have multiple different Contract names so i think i might need to define the text to equal a sheet. So maybe `Set BRVOIDS = Sheet.name("2781")` `Set BRREPAIRS = Sheet.name("2780")` and so on until all sheets are defined.

When the data gets copied i need it to find the last row in column a that has data, when it is found it will insert the copied row into the sheet. for example `EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown`.

I dont have any code at the moment. I would really appreciate all the assistance.

Comment: Is your question about the mechanics of the copy/pasting or about how to determine the target sheets of the individual copy operations? I gather that your question is about the latter, but if so you haven't given enough information. How do you know that BRREPAIRS should target Sheet 2870? If you say where that information comes from then maybe we can suggest a solution.

Comment: @JohnColeman, Hi its a little about both, by mainly about the individual copy orperation. I have a list that tells what what each code represents.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do things like `Set BRVOIDS = Sheet.name("2781")`. In fact, that would be positively harmful since then you would need to run the data in Column Q through a possibly large `Select` statement to know what variable to use. Instead, you could write a function like

```
Function TargetSheet(ContractName As String) As Worksheet
    'code which uses your secret list to determine target sheet
    'Maybe a Select statement, Maybe a Vlookup -- who knows?
    Set TargetSheet = 'sheet your code determined
End Function
```

Sounds like your code will be scanning down column Q, determining where to copy the corresponding row to. Once you get the above function working, you could combine it with something like this:

```
Function LastRow(TargetCol As Variant, Optional ws As Variant) As Range
    'assumes TargetCol is something like 1 or "A"
    Dim n As Long

    If IsMissing(ws) Then Set ws = ActiveSheet
    n = ws.Cells(1, TargetCol).EntireColumn.Rows.Count
    Set LastRow = ws.Cells(n, TargetCol).End(xlUp).EntireRow
End Function
```

This returns as a range the last row containing data (or row 1 if the column is empty) in a specified column in a specified worksheet (which defaults to the Active sheet).

You haven't given enough to go on, but something along the lines of

```
LastRow("A",TargetSheet(Range("Q" & i).Value)).Insert Shift := xlDown
```

Might be what you are looking for. Why don't you try to work it out and ask another question (if need be) once you have some actual code?